# Polarity and Solubility of Tetracyclone

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, solubility, polarity

In one of my organic chemistry experiments, I synthesized tetracyclone (Tetraphenylcyclopentadienone), and we were supposed to dissolve it in DCM to do our TLC.

DCM is polar and looking at the structure of tetracyclone I think it is non polar, isn't there a saying that "like dissolves like"? Then how could tetracyclone dissolve in DCM?

Below is the structure of DCM and tetracyclone:

[image]
[image]

**Edit:** After searching online, I found that due to the lack in ability to form hydrogen bonds, we treat DCM as a non polar solvent, even though it is weakly polar.

Website: https://www.quora.com/Is-CH2Cl2-both-polar-and-non-polar-Why

Comment: Tetraphenylcyclopentadienone is a polar moleule.  Look at the resonance structure with a positive charge on oxygen and a negative charge delocalized within the 5-membered ring.  This would make the ring aromatic with 6 pi electrons.  Therefore such dipolar structures are significant descriptors of the molecule, making it polar.

Comment: My comment is: surely it dissolved as the experiments are pre-checked? The molecule has a dipole moment, same as DCM.@Ron - I've seen the charge split you're talking about for cyclopropenone where the positive charge is on the carbon to give a ring with 2-pi electrons, with a negative charge on the oxygen. I've not seen anything with a positive charge on the oxygen and negative on the carbon.

Comment: @Beerhunter Yes, tetracyclone dissolved in DCM no problem. I asked my professor and she said that DCM is in between polar and non polar, so it can dissolve both polar and non polar substances.

Comment: @ron, but the tendency for oxygen to have a positive charge, plus octet deficiency isnt quite stabilized by aromaticity. Molecule might be polar, but not so polar.